# ngrx create nested state by domain and ui data

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I'm using ngrx entities, and ideally I would like to achieve the following state structure:

```
 state = {
    domainData: {
       userEntities: {
          entities: {},
          ids: []
       }
    },

    ui: {
       usersView: {}
    }
 }
```

This will allow me to separate my data storage from UI related stuff. I can't seem to find a way to do this though. At the moment what I'm doing is this:

I have a separate store module. I have created a reducer for userEntities and a reducer for usersView. Then, with `ActionReducerMap` I have created a combined reducer like so:

```
 const reducer: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    userEntities: userEntitiesReducer,
    usersView: usersViewReducer
 }
```

Then I import `StoreModule.forRoot(reducer)` in my store module. It works, but the structure of the resulting state is not how I would like it to be. Is there any way I can fix it?

Thanks.